# Unable to view map using mapView in android studio

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-mapview

I am new to android development. I am working on Android Studio and developing an app on which i have 3 tabs. One tab is for maps, second is for camera and 3rd is for pictures. I am using google map for viewing map. The map will show current GPS location of the user. For this i am using a `mapView`and done all of the work, but still unable to view the map.

Below is my manifest

```
  <permission android:name="com.example.accurat.faisal.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.accurat.faisal.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<application
     android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="MY_Key"
        />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

The location class is as follows

```
public class MyLocation extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
LocationListener{

GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
MapView mapView;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
TextView tv_loc;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // inflat and return the layout
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_location, container, false);
    mapView = (MapView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.map);
    tv_loc = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);

    return rootView;

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    //stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
    if(mGoogleApiClient !=null)
    {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap=googleMap;
    mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Location Permission already granted
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            //Request Location Permission
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    double lattitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }
    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lattitude, longitude);
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("I am here");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    tv_loc.append("Lattitude: " + lattitude + "  Longitude: " + longitude);

    //move map camera
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

    //stop location updates
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

}

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
private void checkLocationPermission() {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                    .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

    /*super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);*/
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // location-related task you need to do.
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    if(mGoogleApiClient == null)
                    {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {
                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
                //finish();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }
        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}


@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();

}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}}
```

**Update 1**

Below is my layout for location

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.accurat.faisal.MyLocation$PlaceholderFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/section_label"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/map" /></RelativeLayout>
```

When i run my app i just see an empty tab, map doesn't shows. I must be missing something and i don't know what. I have searched many articles on it but couldn't find appropriate help so that's why i am posting  a question here.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: on which version are you running? Sure you've added permissions ?

Comment: @OBX i tested it on different devices with apk starting from `16-23` but the map is not showing and yes i have added permission check(s)

Comment: Throw a breakpoint in `onMapReady` and see if it's hit. Can you also post the contents of `R.layout.my_location`?

Comment: @degs kindly see the `update 1`

Comment: Are you using genymotion?

Comment: remember to hide your API key or other secret value in when you post code

Comment: @MidasLefko no i am testing it on my device(s)

Comment: @VivekMishra yes i forgot to hide it

Comment: so does your onMapReady method gets called or not?

Comment: @VivekMishra debuggin it

Comment: You did not initialize map.   Add "MapsInitializer.initialize(this);" to the onCreate method of the Fragment

Comment: @VivekMishra the `onMapReady` is not called i put a break point on the method but it doesn't hit it

Comment: see this link and search for other related stuff to this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36809284/mapview-onmapready-never-called-in-fragment-for-load-google-map-in-mapview

Comment: @RameshKumar as per your recommendation i have added `MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());` before `mapView.getMapAsync(this);` but still i am unable to see the map

Comment: Did you get any error log in logcat?

Comment: @VivekMishra i was using `map fragment` and it was working but the problem was that my app crashes when i move from tabs to tabs, so i searched it and found that `mapView` is the good solution for it. My app is not crashing now but i am not able to see map

Comment: @RameshKumar no error on logcat