# using google map in a fragment: onMapReady is never called

Tags: android, google-maps

I use in another fragment google maps that works fine. So when I had to do it for another fragment, inside the same app, I copy/paste the code and adapted the inflator and the findviewbyid. But onMapReady() is never called so googlemap stays null.

I've seen the [MapView.onMapReady never called in Fragment for load Google Map in MapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36809284/mapview-onmapready-never-called-in-fragment-for-load-google-map-in-mapview) case which looks similar to mine but I'd like to understand the "implements OnMapReadyCallback" mechanism.

What is the mechanism to call onMapReady? I suppose when the call to mapView.getMapAsync(this) happens?

```
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ScrollView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


    public class LocalisationMonitoringFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
        private Context context;
        private static View view;

        private MapView mapView;

        static private GoogleMap googleMap;

        public LocalisationMonitoringFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.localization_monitor, null);

            mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.loc_mapView);
            mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mapView.onResume();
            mapView.getMapAsync(this);
            try {
         MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return (view);

        }

   @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        googleMap = map;
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker Title").snippet("Marker Description"));
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(sydney).zoom(12).build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    }
```

in the layout file I have:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/loc_mapView"
        android:layout_below="@id/loc_name_txt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's never a good idea to store a `View` into a `static` field. The same applies to your `GoogleMap` variable.

Second, I don't see why you should call `onResume()` right after you call `onCreate(Bundle)` from your `mapView`.

Maybe that `onResume()` call may already be the issue.

---

**About the life-cycle mechanism**

It means (e.g.); the `onPause()` method in your fragment should call the `onPause()` method of the `MapView`.

```
@Override protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    this.mapView.onPause();
}
```

You should then implement other life-cycle methods with the same logic:

- `onDestroy()`
- `onResume()`
- `onLowMemory()`
- `onSaveInstanceState()`
- `onStop()`
- `onCreate(Bundle)`

Also, of course, if you haven't registered a Google Maps API Key, your Map will not show up. So make sure you also did that. You never know...

---

By looking at **a project of mine**, which feature a fully-working `MapView` inside a `Fragment` I see I had overridden the life-cycle methods in this way:

```
@Override protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (this.mapView != null)
        this.mapView.onPause();
}
```

Don't know if it's necessary in your case. I had a few cases in which the `MapView` wasn't initialized and threw a `NullPointerException`. Test without it, then if it's necessary add a `null` check.

Moreover, I actually left out the following methods:

- `onSaveInstanceState()`
- `onStop()`
- `onCreate(Bundle)`

They were all the cause of some crashes in my application, so I did not override them.

Still, **implement it** as [the docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView) say. If you run into some issues, you may try what I did.

Moreover, in `onCreateView(...)` I called

```
MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());
```

before

```
this.mapView = (MapView) ...;
```

My `onCreateView(...)` method looked like this.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location, container, false);
    MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());

    this.mapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    this.mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.mapView.getMapAsync(this);
    // initialize other UI elements.
    return this.rootView;
}
```

Although I doubt it, the issues I mentioned above, may have happened because I used the `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`version instead of the `android.app.Fragment;` one.

Comment: I did several test. thanks for your detailed answer. I removed mapview.resume, static def, tried to apply your suggestions. Still onmapready is not called?? I'm going to try more to simplify.

Comment: Ok @narb can you tell me what api level you are targeting and what is the min level? Also are you sure in the console you see nothing about the mapview when your fragment becomes visible? Even if you set the filter to 'none'?

Comment: The discussion with you helped me finding there was no crazy thing in my code. In fact what happens is that it takes somewhat some time for onMapReady to be called. so if you try to go too fast (what happened to me:)) googlemap is null. thx to you!

Comment: @narb glad you did it by yourself. Still, it seems that your **some time** is too much time. Unless you are using an extremely slow internet connection, `onMapReady()` should be called within a few seconds at most.

Comment: I'm talking about  microsec. I call getMapAsync and MapsInitializer in createview and I was calling an addmarker in onactivitycreated.

Comment: Probably if you included the add-marker detail in your question you would have gotten a straightforward answer ;) @narb

Comment: :) I'm still struggling. I need to click multiple times on the map so that it appears. and I get strange messages from the garbage collector: sticky concurrent mark sweep GC

Comment: @narb it would great if you posted more details on your questions, such as your `Activity` code that owns the `Fragment` and an extensive log of when you open your `MapView`

Comment: I'll try to simplify it and I agree I need to post more details. I'll open a new Q for it. Many thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

In my Fragment's xml file, I have used the following:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/googleMap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In the Fragment.kt file, I have used the following:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fram_map_fragment, container, false)
    initMap(view, savedInstanceState)
    return view
}

private fun initMap(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    mapView = view?.findViewById(R.id.googleMap)
    mapView?.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    mapView?.getMapAsync(this)
}

override fun onMapReady(map: GoogleMap?) {
    googleMap = map
    googleMap?.moveCamera(
        CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            LatLng(lat, lng),
            17F
        )
    )
    googleMap?.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE
    googleMap?.setOnMapClickListener {
        // Create Marker
        drawMarkers(it)
    }
}

override fun onResume() {
    mapView?.onResume()
    super.onResume()
}

override fun onPause() {
    mapView?.onPause()
    super.onPause()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    mapView?.onDestroy()
    super.onDestroy()
}

override fun onLowMemory() {
    mapView?.onLowMemory()
    super.onLowMemory()
}
```

And it is working perfectly.